# How to create objects from different data sources/formats

Tags: java, design-patterns, gson, ormlite

I'm working on project where I need to create objects from different data sources/formats. I would like to know what is the best way to organize source code to make it easy.

Let's say I have class User and I want to have ability to create objects from data from database and JSON. The purpose of it is letting user of my app to browse data online and offline. I'm using GSON and ORMLite. In addition fields in JSON and database may be different, but the "main" fields are the same. Is it a good idea to create class which contains all properties/fields from JSON and database? Something similar to class below:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "user", daoClass = UserDaoImpl.class)
public class User {

    public static final String ID_FIELD_NAME = "id";
    public static final String USER_LOGIN_FIELD_NAME = "login";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL_FIELD_NAME = "email";
    public static final String SERIALIZED_COUNTRY_FIELD_NAME = "user_county";

    // DB & JSON
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    int id;

    // DB & JSON
    @DatabaseField(columnName = USER_LOGIN_FIELD_NAME)
    String login;

    //DB & JSON
    @DatabaseField(columnName = USER_EMAIL_FIELD_NAME)
    String email;

    //Only JSON
    @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_COUNTRY_FIELD_NAME)
    String country;

    public Track() {

    }
}
```

Comment: what u r intended to do ?

Comment: I'm creating mobile app where user can browse other users online and when he wants save data to db. I would like to have ability to easily switch between datasource when user is offline or online. If online - I fetch JSON from web server and dsplay it to the user, if offline - I display data from database.

Comment: understood, so you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to create class which contains all properties/fields from JSON and database?

I think the short answer is yes.  You can certain use the same objects to represent the data in the database and via JSON.

When you will get into problems is when you need to change the data representations in the database but don't want to change your JSON API or vice versa.  Then you will need 2 separate classes and a mapping function between them.

But if you can get away with one class then that's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

consider the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), you can use it to abstract the creation of concrete user classes as a function of the data source.

make User into an interface, and have a data-source specific implementation of User for each type of data source.